# Exit from Shell script without executing anything

Tags: shell, unix, command, exit

I have a shell script installed to run every day. 
The script consists of some rm (delete) commands and SCP commands for file transfer. The script is failing due to some errors in production. I want the job to return exit code as 0 without executing anything, so I wrote

```
exit 0;
```

at the beginning of the shell script so that as soon as the script executes, it will exit with out any commands after that exit 0; but still the script is failing.

I cannot edit the whole contents inside the file nor delete the script or contents inside the script.

Please suggest whether I am using the right syntax for exit command or how to make the script to exit with return code 0 as soon as it starts executing.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The ';' is unnecessary. You can exit like this:

```
exit
exit 1
```

[This is a description about 'Exit and Exit Status'.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)